# "deren" vs. "ihres" to mark ownership

Tags: pronoun, possessive-pronoun

Under the usage of *der/die/das* as a demonstrative pronoun, [leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Pronomen/FRegeln-P/Demonstr/Pron-der-die-das.xml?lang=de) lists the usage of *dessen/deren* to mark ownership clearly. As an example, the site gives -

> 1. Herr Müller geht mit Anton und seiner Schwester weg.
> 2. Herr Müller geht mit Anton und dessen Schwester weg.

In the first sentence, "Schwester" can be either "Herr Müller’s" or
Anton’s sister. In the second sentence, "Schwester" must be Anton’s
sister, because "dessen" can‘t refer to the subject of the sentence
"Herr Müller".

There is another sentence on the webpage, that I can‘t fit into this rule:

> Er liebt nicht die Frau, sondern deren Geld.

Since there is no confusion between the masculine subject "er" and feminine "die Frau", I would  have written "ihres Geld". I’m not sure why "deren" is being used here.

Comment: I would have written "ihr Geld" (not "ihres"). Indeed, "deren" sounds weird, but perhaps the author wanted to make cler that it is "ihr" = "her" money and not "ihr" = "their" common money.

Comment: What sounds weird with "deren"? How would you use "deren"? Or do you suggest to abandon it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

> Er liebt nicht die Frau, sondern <del>*ihres*</del> Geld.

This is correct:

> Er liebt nicht die Frau, sondern **ihr** Geld.

Here *"ihr"* is a possessive pronoun and *"ihr Geld"* is an accusative object. It has to be an accusative object because it has to match with *"die Frau"* which also is an accusative object. And this is because the verb *»lieben«* needs its object in accusative case.

This is correct too, but another construction:

> Er liebt nicht die Frau, sondern **deren** Geld.

The word *"deren"* is not a possessive pronoun (i.e pronoun of ownership) but a demonstrative pronoun (i.e. a referring pronoun) in genitive case while *"deren Geld"* still is an accusative object. Here the demonstrative pronoun is some kind of genitive attribute of the noun *»Geld«* like in this sentence:

> Er liebt nicht die Frau, sondern **Susannes** Geld.

To have a genitive demonstrative pronoun in an accusative object is possible and it is correct, but it is confusing (also to native speakers). Genitive attributes which are nouns are o.k. (like *»Er liebt Susannes Geld«*) but when you have the choice between

1. > Er liebt ihr Geld.

and

2. > Er liebt deren Geld.

then #1 is the better choice.

Comment: Probier das mal mit einem Kätzchen statt Geld. Das Geld, das Kätzchen ... - liebt er nicht die Frau, sondern ihr Kätzchen liebt die Frau? Nein, der Mann liebt nicht die Frau, sondern deren Kätzchen. Nur letzteres ist eindeutig, daher halte ich "ihr Geld" für nur zufällig korrekt, denn das Geld liebt die Frau ja eher nicht - allenfalls in einem sehr weit hergeholten Sinne von "Die Scheine fliegen mir nur so zu, das Geld liebt mich!", welches in den meisten Fällen vom Kontext her ausscheidet. "Deren" ist eindeutig besser, auch wenn es für HvE weird klingt.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. I found the comparison to "Susannes Geld" very helpful.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich kann dir nicht ganz folgen. »Er liebt nicht die Frau sondern deren Kätzchen« und »Er liebt nicht die Frau sondern ihr Kätzchen« bedeuten doch genau dasselbe. Der Mann (oder der Kater, jedenfalls das männliche Subjekt des Satzes) liebt in beiden Fällen das Kätzchen und empfindet keine Liebe für die Frau. In beiden Sätzen ist das Subjekt (*»er«*) nach wie vor jene Partei, die die Handlung ausübt, und das ist in diesem Fall *»lieben«.* Und wegen der *nicht-sondern*-Konstruktion gibt es zwei grammatikalische Liebesobjekte, ...

Comment: ...nämlich (in verneinter Form) die Frau und (in bestätigter Form) das Kätzchen (oder das Geld im anderen Beispiel). Die von dir behauptete Bedeutung steck nicht in diesen Sätzen, wohl aber in diesen: »Nicht er, sondern das Kätzchen/das Geld liebt die Frau.« Diese Konstruktion stand aber nicht zur Diskussion.